# Using Concat within a Rails Scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Contact` model.  It has the attributes: `first_name` and `last_name`.  The user enters text in a search field with the prompt: **Enter the contact's full name**.  Rails then needs to find all contact records `LIKE` the name entered.
Here is a picture of the contact records:

[image: Picture of records within the Contact Table]

-If the user types in "JOE" then rails will return two records (because it is case insensitive)

-If the user types in "joe s" then rails will return two records

-If the user types in "doe" then rails will return one record.

```
#models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_entered_name, -> (full_name){where("CONCAT('first_name',' ','last_name') LIKE ?", full_name)}
end
```

Generated sql when I run `Contact.by_entered_name("joe")` in the rails console:

```
SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE (CONCAT('first_name',' ','last_name') LIKE 'joe'
```

I am using mysql in case that detail is important. For this example app however, I am using sqlite, and it is throwing a syntax error.  Ultimately what is most important is that I get this to work on mysql.

**Update:** It was expressed that my question was not clear.  My question is:

How do I properly create a query which takes text entered by a user, and finds all `contacts` whose concatenated `first_name` and `last_name` are `LIKE` that submitted text by the user?  I also need it to be case insensitive.  My attempted scope above does not appear to work.

Comment: so... whats your question?

Comment: have a read on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html but the answer would just be to change `full_name` to `"%#{full_name}%"` so that it matches the any name which contains the search query

Comment: @sevenseacat I updated my original question.  Hopefully that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some quotes in there you don't need.  And you need the wildcard `%` in the parameter.  Also, ILIKE is needed to disregard the case with Postgres.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_entered_name, -> (full_name){where("CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) ILIKE ?", "%#{full_name}%")}
end
```

Comment: Nitpick but I would change it to LIKE %?% instead of putting that with the input

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't use the `CONCAT` function, it uses `||` as a concatenation operator. Swards' answer will get you going in MySQL.